# In Brouwer's theorem, how does the absence of fixed points imply certain retraction properties?

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of Brouwer's theorem form Lawvere and Schanuel's *Conceptual Mathematics*:

> To prove that the non-existence of a retraction implies that every
>   continuous endomap has a fixed point, all we need to do is to assume
>   that there is a continuous endomap of the disk which does not have any
>   fixed point, and to build from it a continuous retraction for the
>   inclusion of the circle into the disk.

This seems to involve unspoken assumptions that I don't know how to justify. If the non-existence of the retraction proves $ \exists x[f(x) = x] $, then I believe that it must also be true that the lack of fixed points $ \forall x[f(x) \neq x] $ implies the existence of a retraction <s>which shares the same property as the endomap</s>, namely:

$$∀x[(f(x) \neq x)] \to \exists r[r \circ j = 1_C]$$

(Edit note: this expression was originally $∀x[(f(x) \neq x) \to (r(x) \neq x)]$. I mistakenly thought that contradicting $ r(x) \neq x$ was necessary to the argument.)

**So my question is twofold:**

- How does the lack of a fixed point in the endomap *imply* (as opposed to simply making possible) the existence of a retraction, $ r \circ j = 1_C $?
- Why is it assumed that the retraction must have properties that <s>behave as the endomap</s> lead to a contradiction? In other words, it seems like they could be completely independent so that it's both true that $ \forall x[f(x) \neq x] $ and $ r \circ j = 1_C $.

**Here's the proof from the book:**

[image]

> So, let $ j: C \to D $ be the inclusion map of the circle into the
>   disk as its boundary, and let's assume that we have an endomap of the
>   disk, $ f: D \to D $, *which does not have any fixed point*. This
>   means that for every point $x$ in the disk $D$, $f(x) \neq x.$
>
> From this we are going to build a retraction for $j$, i.e. a map $r: D
> \> \to C$ such that $r \circ j$ is the identity on the circle. The key to
>   the construction is the assumed property of $f$, namely that for every
>   point $x$ in the disk, $f(x)$ is different from $x$. Draw an arrow
>   with its tail at $f(x)$ and its head at $x$. This arrow will 'point
>   to' some point $r(x)$ on the boundary. When $x$ was already a point on
>   the boundary, $r(x)$ is $x$ itself, so that $r$ is a retraction for
>   $j$, i.e. $rj= 1_c$.

(The book doesn't assume any knowledge about topology nor do I know much about it.)

Answer (score 4):

You can't construct a retraction if there is a fixed point because the basic ingredient in the construction of the retraction is the displacement direction $f(x)-x$, which can be normalized to get a unit vector. If the displacement is zero then you can't get a unit vector because you can't divide by zero. In more detail, with regard to your question

> How does the lack of a fixed point in the endomap imply the existence of a retraction, $ r \circ j = 1_C $?

The answer is that the absence of a fixed point of the endomap is what allows one to define a *continuous* retraction.  With regard to your question

> Why is it assumed that the retraction must behave as the endomap? In other words, it seems like they could be completely independent so that it's both true that $ \forall x[f(x) \neq x] $ and $ \exists x [r(x) = x]$

The retraction itself (when it is defined, i.e. so long as the endomap has no fixed points) satisfies $r(x)=x$ for all points $x$ on the boundary, by construction of $r$.

As I mentioned in the *comments*, the account provided by the authors you cite leaves an essential topological fact unmentioned. This is the fact that the identity map of the circle cannot be extended over the disk.

Comment: People keep saying that that's the basic ingredient, but I've yet to find anyone explain why. But, even so, my question is about about why is it assumed that a retraction is necessary. How does the lack of a fixed point in the endomap imply the existence of a retraction?

Comment: The retraction needs to be a continuous map (otherwise you haven't accomplished anything since one can certainly always find a *discontinous* "retraction"). If there is no fixed point then the trick with normalizing the displacement vector produces a continuous retraction.

Comment: I understand, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Wait a minute, you need to know what the basic strategy of Brouwer's proof is.  Modern proofs usually use either a homology argument or a homotopy argument. The point is that the existence of such a retraction would contradict the nonvanishing of such a class. For example, the relative homology class of the disk with respect to its boundary is nonzero.  If a retraction existed, it would imply that such a class is zero, which gives a contradiction.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. If $ \neg R \to F $ is a relevant argument, it is so in virtue of $ \neg F \to R $. You keep addressing $ \neg R $ but my question is about the basis for $ \neg F \to R $.

Comment: @PédeLeão, These are equivalent statements in classical logic!  And in intuitionistic logic the theorem is not valid, as Brouwer himself pointed out at length. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: The form of argument is *reductio ad absurdum* (a negation of an assumption implying the conclusion: $ \neg R \to F $) whose contradiciton in terms of $R$ would be $R \land \neg R$. My question is not about showing that the redaction leads to contradiction, but on what bases its hypothetical existence is even part of the argument: $ \neg F \to R $. As I asked from the start: How does the lack of a fixed point in the endomap imply the existence of a retraction? Why is it assumed that the retraction must behave as the endomap?

Comment: By the way, the fact that they are equivalent statements is what makes the proof work. All valid proofs can be expressed as tautologies.

Comment: Also fom your answer: "The absence of a fixed point of the endomap is what allows one to define a continuous retraction." The key word is *allows* because that's not the same as implication. If the existence of the retraction is only a trivial possibility, then proving its non-existence is also trivial.

Comment: Concerning your edit: I realize that the retraction satisfies $ r(x) = x $ on the boundary, but I see no reason that it *has to*. That's why I said that it must somehow be implied by $ f $, and that is also why I said that $ r $  is assumed to resemble its behavior in this respect. My question is "*Why* is it assumed" that this is so.

Comment: The wording of the passage you cited is  a bit confusing.  What they should be saying is that, given an endomap with no fixed points, you can construct a retraction $r: D^2\to S^1$ such that the restriction of $r$ to the boundary is the identity map. This contradicts the nontriviality of a suitable homology or homotopy class.

Comment: What's important is not the wording of the passage but whatever is necessary to make the proof work. The idea that you *can construct* is simply not enough for a sound proof. The hypothesis must imply the existence of the retraction *and* some property (such as $ r(x) = x $) that can serve as a basis for contradiction. Without both of these, the proof seems to fail. Therefore, a proper answer to my question would abandon the idea of possible existence of $ r $ that *might* exhibit such and such a property.

Comment: I didn't see their particular proof but the point is that if you can connect the identity map of the disk to a map to the boundary via a homotopy that respects the boundary, i.e., the boundary is sent to itself throughout the homotopy, this would contradict the nontriviality of the famous class. Whether or not the boundary is actually fixed pointwise is immaterial.

Comment: If the boundary isn't fixed pointwise, doesn't that undermine the possibility for contradiction? It seems the boundary must have fixed points for that because, otherwise, each point could map to another. In addition to that, what you're saying doesn't seem to address the question as to how the hypothesis implies the retraction.

Comment: The point is that the relative fundamental class of $(D^2, S^1)$ is invariant under such homotopies. You don't need the boundary to be fixed pointwise.

Comment: OK. But you still haven't answered my question. I'm still lacking any sound principles to show that the hypothesis implies a contradiction.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  The sound principle is that the image of the relative fundamental class is invariant under a homotopy.  At the beginning of the homotopy the image was nontrivial, whereas at the end of the homotopy the image is trivial. This gives the desired contradiction.

Comment: Maybe so, but I don't know what any of that means, and it's not part of your answer anyway.

Comment: Well then you should try to understand how their proof works.  It is hard to help you if we don't know what the proof is.  I don't have their book in front of me. So you say they don't use a relative fundamental class?

Comment: I edited the question to include the proof from the book.

Comment: They sweep under the rug the ingredient from algebraic topology. To reach a contradiction you need to know that there is no such retraction. Namely, the identity map of the circle does not extend across the unit disk while keeping the image in the circle. This is due to the fact that the fundamental group of the circle is nontrivial. Their topological ingredient is a little different from what I thought. At any rate you can't follow this without using the nontriviality of the fundamental group or some equivalent topological fact.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. I'm hoping you're wrong about me not being able to understand it. :-) I simply don't have time to study topology right now.

Comment: @PédeLeão, I didn't say *you* can't follow it. I only said that one can't follow it without knowing an ingredient from algebraic topology which is equivalent to the fact that the identity map of the circle to itself cannot be homotoped to a constant map.

Answer (score 2):

The claim made is essentially: suppose we can show that there is no continuous retraction from $B^n$ onto $S^{n-1}$ (you would use homotopy or homology to show that, usually).

Then every continuous $f: B^n \to B^n$ (an endomap) has a fixed point.
Reason: if we have any such endomap $f$ *without a fixed point*, then define $r(x)$ as the unique point of intersection of the ray $x + t(f(x) -x), t \in [0,\infty)$ with $S^{n-1}$ having the smallest $t$, is well-defined (as $f(x) \neq x$ on $B^n$, we always have a non-zero vector as a direction for the ray), continuous (hint [here, e.g.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2029162)) and a retraction from $B^n \to S^{n-1}$, (for $x \in S^{n-1}$ $t=0$ is the first intersection point, so $r(x) = x$) which we have shown to be impossible.

Note that also that having no such retraction is a necessary condition for the fixed point property: if we'd have such an $r$ we could define $f = h\circ r: B^n \to B^n$, where $h$ is a non-trivial rotation of $S^{n-1}$,and this $f$ has no fixed point (points inside map to points on the boundary, so are never fixed, and on the boundary $r$ keeps them fixed but $h$ moves them).

So the fixed point property for $B^n$ (i.e. Brouwer's theorem) is equivalent to the no-retraction theorem, in the sense that one is easily derived from the other.

Comment: Your reason: "if we have any such endomap $f$ without a fixed point..." only implies that the retraction would be well defined and continuous. It doesn't, however, imply that its existence would be a necessary consequence. If the existence of the retraction is only a trivial possibility, then proving it's non-existence is also trivial. Therefore, there has to be some logical connection between the endomap and the retraction: $ ∀x[(f(x) \neq x) \to (r(x) \neq x)] $. Otherwise it's completely irrelevant to the proof.

Comment: Yes, if we have a fixed point free endomap, we necessarily have a retraction. The argument I gave shows that. The point is that most proofs will argue the nonexistence of such a retraction. I don't understand your $r(x)\neq x$ remark. Retractions have a lot of fixed points, the whole of $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: I don't see how your argument shows that. I understand $ r(x) \neq x $ as the means for demonstrating the contradiction. Since retractions have a lot of fixed points, the assumption that the endomap has no fixed points is proved false by contradiction, *assuming* that the existence of the retraction is a necessary consequence of a fixed-point-free endomap. That latter part seems to be lacking in your argument.

Comment: @PédeLeão I added the improved argument for the existence of the retraction. Non-existence of the retraction is non-trivial. $r(x) \neq x$ is not the contradiction but the fact a retraction exists at all, is.

Comment: You still don't seem to understand my question. You say, "If we have a fixed point free endomap, we necessarily have a retraction." By how? Based on what? Claiming that you *can* define a retraction is not a necessary consequence. You say that $ r(x) \neq x $ is not the contradiction, but you also say $ r(x) = x $ is impossible. The conjunction of those two is precisely the contradiction I was talking about. If it could be shown that a fixed-point-free endomap implied such a contradiction, the proof would make sense to me, but you haven't suggested any way that it does so.

Comment: @PédeLeão You can define a contraction from a fixed-point free endomap. We prove first that such a retraction cannot exist. So a fixed-point free endomap cannot exist either: Brouwer holds. "Necessary consequence" is superfluous, it's just a " (logical) consequence".  The exact logical formulation would be $(\exists f: B^n \to B^n \text{ continuous } (\forall x \in B^n f(x) \neq x)) \rightarrow (\exists r: B^n \rightarrow S^{n-1} \text{ a continuous retraction})$ and we can show that the conclusion does not hold (so we show $\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p$ from this $p \rightarrow q$.

Comment: Sure you *can* define a reduction that leads to an impossible consequence. Everyone is saying so, and I'm disputing that at all. It's simply *not* what I'm asking.

Comment: My question is about how this can be justified: $ (\exists f: B^n \to B^n \text{ continuous } (\forall x \in B^n f(x) \neq x)) \rightarrow (\exists r: B^n \rightarrow S^{n-1} \text{ a continuous retraction}) $. How does the existence of $ f $ imply the retraction? There's nothing in your answer that addresses that. It simply assumes it.

Comment: @PédeLeão I give the construction using the point of intersection with the ray. This $r(x)$ is constructed from such an $f$

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I'm asking.

Comment: You ask "how does the lack of a fixpoint lead to the existence of a retraction?" That's what the definition of $r$ shows.

Comment: But my point is that its doesn't show that at all. The proposition $ \neg F \to R $ is falsified by $ F \land \neg R $. The ability to define $ R $ establishes nothing about its existence. Therefore, it's possible that $ R $ does not exist and $ \neg F \to R $ is false.

Comment: The possibility to define it **shows** its existence. $\neg F \to R$ is **only** falsified by $\neg F \land \neg R$. We show $F$ because we can define $r$ from a counterexample to $F$. This shows $\neg F \to R$ which is equivalent to $\neg R \to F$ by contraposition. As we supposedly have shown $\neg R$ we conclude $F$.

Comment: I believe you're right that the possibility of defining $R$ implies its existence. Along with the implication is the assumption that all other conditions are present. Given $(C_1 \land C_2 \land \neg F) \to R$, it follows that $(\neg R \land C_1 \land C_2) \to F$, so $F$ can be concluded assuming that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are true but *not* relevant to the contradiction. That just might be the unspoken assumption that was obvious to everyone, but it wasn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

The claim being made is actually (roughly)
$$(\exists r)(r\,\mathrm{is\,a\,retraction})\implies (\forall f)(\exists x)(f(x)=x)$$
which is distinct from the formula you gave. I do not know if this is the source of your confusion, but it's worth pointing out.

For your first question, suppose $f:B^n\to B^n$ has no fixed point. When we may define $r: B^n\to S^{n-1}$ as follows: given $x\in B^n$, consider the unique line intersecting both $x$ and $f(x)$ (this line is unique because $f(x)\neq x$). Then define $r(x)$ to be the point of intersection of this line with the sphere, on the side of $f(x)$. This defines a continuous retraction from the ball to its boundary.

Thus, proving that no retraction exists from the ball to its boundary is sufficient to prove the Brouwer fixed point theorem. For if there were a map with no fixed point, as shown, we could contruct such a retraction. This should clarify your second question as well.

Comment: The claim that you're making is irrelevant if the retraction need not exist. If an endomap, free of fixed points, could exist without a retraction, it doesn't make sense to posit any arguments about the retraction's properties.